# Authentication Failure using Git-LFS Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-lfs

I'm getting the following Authentication failure attempting to checkout a repository with git-lfs support in an Azure Devops Pipeline:

```
##[command]git -c http.<url>="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" lfs fetch origin 8d51d72484c1b19a2427ed9f7736d410e43a8a29
fetch: Fetching reference 8d51d72484c1b19a2427ed9f7736d410e43a8a29
fatal: could not read Password for '<url>': terminal prompts disabled
batch response: Git credentials for <url> not found.
error: failed to fetch some objects from '<url>/info/lfs'
##[warning]Git lfs fetch failed with exit code 2, back off 5.476 seconds before retry.
```

The repo is also hosted on Azure DevOps, and the pipeline is configured as follows:

```
jobs:
...
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    lfs: true
    persistCredentials: true
```

It succeeds without lfs enabled, but only downloads the file pointers. What credentials does it require, and how do I supply them?

Comment: it should work with lfs enabled. can you verify your repo actually contains lfs files and not pointers?

Comment: Yes. `git lfs ls-files` lists the correct files, and `git lfs pull` gets the files from the repository when run locally. It's only when running on the Azure pipeline that authentication fails.

Comment: i'm having this issue too, literally just followed the instructions in the azure devops doco and this error pops up

Comment: Same issue here. Mine actually succeeds the first time git lfs fetch is called and fails the second time. It happens to have a different URL the second time it's called and the authentication seems to fail because of it.