# Unable to download the source code in Azure DevOps Release

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I have spring boot application in Azure Repo. I'm trying to deploy the application using docker on Azure App Service through Azure DevOps Release Pipeline. Having an issue to download the source code artifacts in the release pipeline.

Error Message:

> 2021-01-03T11:13:10.5485744Z ##[error]Downloading artifacts failed: System.InvalidOperationException: Git lfs fetch failed with exit code: 2. Git lfs logs returned with exit code: 0.
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.TfsGitArtifact.DownloadAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String downloadFolderPath)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass39_2.<b__2>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Func1 action)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifacts(IExecutionContext executionContext, IList1 agentArtifactDefinitions, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifactsAndCommitsAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Object data)
> 2021-01-03T11:13:10.5536373Z ##[error]Git lfs fetch failed with exit code: 2. Git lfs logs returned with exit code: 0.

[image]
Please advice.

Comment: Does it look like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735763/authentication-failure-using-git-lfs-azure-devops-pipeline

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Nope. I think it is not authentication issue.

Comment: OK. If you think it's not an auth issue perhaps add some detail explaining why you think that. Also, are you using a hosted agent? are you using YAML or the graphical step?

Comment: I have yaml file to create the release pipeline.

Comment: In that case can you post your YAML also? (I probably can't help but it will speed up things if someone else can)

Comment: Hi there, please check whether my answer can help you. If not, could you tell me what agent you are using? Do you get the same error when you download the source code locally?

Comment: Hello there, I haven't got your latest news. Is there any updates on this question? I wonder whether this error occurs on both Microsoft-hosted agent and your self-hosted agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the question may be that your Git and Git LFS versions are too low.

You can try to upgrade to the latest versions to see if the question is resolved.

P.S. If you are using Microsoft-hosted agent for windows and linux, the pre-installed version of GIT LFS is `2.12.1`. Try to update it to `2.13.1`.